# Can the word "rook" be used as a verb in chess?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, ambiguity

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/queen), the word *queen* can be used as a verb with the meaning "to become a queen in chess". I am wondering if the work *rook* can be used in the same way: Is it grammatically correct to use the work *rook* in chess to mean "to become a rook in chess"?

For example:

> White has rooked his pawn to prevent stalemate.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Remember that a sentence can be both grammatically correct and nonsensical. If there is a problem with using *rooked* like that it's not the grammar. (I wouldn't go as far as saying your sentence is nonsensical though, I think it makes sense in context.)

Comment: Are you really asking whether the sentence is **grammatical**? Chomsky's famous sentence "Colourless green ideas sleep furiously" is grammatical, as is yours. If you're really asking whether *rook* exists (or can be understood) as a verb, then do edit the post to ask that question. (Yes, it's in the title; but the body of the question asks something different.)

Comment: At least one problem presents itself: "rook" has a different meaning already as a transitive verb (to cheat or swindle), so this novel usage will be struggling against the established meaning.

Comment: You can use the verb, but people will look at you strangely and, maybe, laugh.

Comment: You can verb any noun so long as it's clear to your readers what you're talking about. But me no buts, as Shakespeare said. But "rooking a pawn" would certainly come over as a novelty.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but humorous: in English, the noun for this piece is "rook" and the verb for the special move it makes simultaneously with the king is "to castle"; in French the name for the piece is "la tour = the tower" and the name for the special move is "roquer = to rook."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatically sound, but isn't idiomatic and doesn't convey the meaning you intend.

Since a queen is the most powerful piece in chess, the typical case is *to promote* your pawn to a queen, or *to queen* your pawn. Much less often, it can be advantageous to promote the pawn to a piece other than a queen.

**promote** (v.)

> Exchange (a pawn) for a more powerful piece of the same colour,
> typically a queen, when it reaches the opponent's end of the board
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/promote)

**underpromotion** (n.)

> The promotion of a pawn to bishop, knight, or rook in chess [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underpromotion)

This happens more frequently in *chess problems* which feature underpromotion as a theme. (Since it's uncommon in actual games, it's often overlooked in a problem.)

The verb here is **to underpromote** (a pawn) (to a rook, bishop, or knight). However, you would usually say "It's better to *promote* to a rook in this case", rather than *underpromote*. The verb *underpromote* would be used in cases like the webpage below: "When is it better to underpromote," where it refers to underpromotion in general.

Although the verb *to underpromote* is used in the chess world, I don't see it in the few dictionaries I've checked. I've need heard or seen *rook, bishop, or knight* used as a verb for pawn promotion  and they sound quite odd, perhaps also because *to rook* and *to knight* have other meanings outside of chess.

*To rook* is "to defraud by cheating or swindling" [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rook). I could understand *White has rooked his pawn to prevent stalemate* to mean that White cheated by surreptitiously removing a pawn from the board to prevent a stalemate.

> **Don't get rooked by scams**
>
> Unfortunately, con artists target senior citizens.  [S. Polgar and
> Douglas Goldstein; *Rich as a King: How the Wisdom of Chess Can Make
> You a King*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rich_as_a_King/K64TBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22get%20rooked%22&pg=PA73&printsec=frontcover)

> Another difficulty: prices. In recent years, Paris has earned the
> reputation of being Europe's most expensive city. Ergo, everybody is
> convinced that you **get rooked** in France no matter where you go.
> But that just isn't so. [*Skiing*, Oct. 1967, p.127](https://books.google.com/books?id=IKnn6dj3xN8C&pg=PA127&dq=%22get%20rooked%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu2ofu65LzAhWzEFkFHYBDA184ChDoAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20rooked%22&f=false)

Some reasons why you would want to underpromote:

> A knight  gives check, checkmate, or forks more than one piece upon promotion where a queen would
> not.
>
> Promoting to a queen would
> stalemate your opponent (giving them no moves and thereby tying a game you could otherwise win).
>
> Other, more technical cases are discussed in the links below.

See also:

["A Guide to **Underpromotion** in Chess"](https://www.chess.com/article/view/a-guide-to-underpromotion)

["When is it Better **to Underpromote**?"](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/endgames/when-is-it-better-to-underpromote)

"Promotion (chess)" at [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_(chess)) has underpromotion statistics

Comment: What meaning does it convey, if not the intended one? It's a way of saying things I've never come across before but in context, for me, the "...to prevent stalemate" makes it pretty clear what they mean. Incidentally, when I first read the title I assumed the question would be about using "rook" as a verb instead of "castle" (ie the usual meaning of "castle" as a verb in chess), and that potential confusion makes the idiom more likely to be misunderstood than for example using "bishop" as a verb in the same way.

Comment: @Rupe I've added an unintended interpretation. However, a grammatical sentence can simply not convey its intended meaning without conveying some other clear meaning.

Comment: Good analysis, although it's also true that *to queen* has meaning outside of chess, just as *to rook* and *to knight* do (though usually it's part of a phrasal verb like "queen around" or "queen it up"). But this is far outweighed by the fact that promotion to queen is the most common pawn promotion.

Comment: While "knighted" does have a meaning outside chess, it's exactly the same as the intended chess meaning (made into a knight), so that would probably be understood more easily than "rooked".

Comment: True, although I don't think a modern queen expects those whom she knights to do battle for her in a game or battle :-) It's simply the rarity of underpromotion that explains why the nouns for these pieces haven't come to be used as verbs.

Comment: @DjinTonic Fair enough, hadn't come across that use of "rook"

Comment: @Rupe I've added  examples of *to rook/get rooked* in the answer.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Also, knight is probably the most common underpromotion in chess, as you'd only do rook or bishop to avoid a stalemate from a queen, which is a much less common phenomenon, while a knight has moves the queen doesn't, and thus is more likely to be useful than rook/bishop.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Yes, which is why I listed it first in the the reasons for underpromoting. Wiki stats: Queen 96.9%; Knight 1.8%; Rook 1.1%; Bishop 0.2%